# ArrayList of hashmap sorting in Java

Tags: java, android

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("Country", "India");
map1.put("State", "Tamilnadu");
map1.put("Distict", "Ariyalur");

HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("Country", "India");
map2.put("State", "Tamilnadu");
map2.put("Distict", "Salem");

HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
map3.put("Country", "India");
map3.put("State", "Tamilnadu");
map3.put("Distict", "Trichy");

HashMap<String, String> map4 = new HashMap<>();
map4.put("Country", "India");
map4.put("State", "Kerala");
map4.put("Distict", "State1");

HashMap<String, String> map5 = new HashMap<>();
map5.put("Country", "Pak");
map5.put("State", "Kerala");
map5.put("Distict", "State1");

mylist.add(map1);
mylist.add(map2);
mylist.add(map3);
mylist.add(map4);
mylist.add(map5);

System.out.println(mylist);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> counstatelist = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
    if (counstatelist.size() > 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < counstatelist.size(); j++) {
            if ((!counstatelist.get(j).get("Country")
                    .equals(mylist.get(i).get("Country")))
                    || (!counstatelist.get(j).get("State")
                            .equals(mylist.get(i).get("State")))) {
                tempMap.put("Country", mylist.get(i).get("Country"));
                tempMap.put("State", mylist.get(i).get("State"));
                counstatelist.add(tempMap);
            }
        }
    } else {
        tempMap.put("Country", mylist.get(i).get("Country"));
        tempMap.put("State", mylist.get(i).get("State"));
        counstatelist.add(tempMap);
    }
}

System.out.println(counstatelist);
```

In this code I want to get group of `Country` and `State` list. 
So my expected output is

```
[{State=Tamilnadu, Country=India}, {State=Kerala, Country=India}, {State=Kerala, Country=Pak}]
```

But this code gives me following output

```
[{State=Tamilnadu, Country=India}, {State=Kerala, Country=India}, {State=Kerala, Country=Pak}, {State=Kerala, Country=Pak}]
```

**Update 1**
I have changed the logic as following.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
    if (counstatelist.size() > 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < counstatelist.size(); j++) {
            if ((!counstatelist.get(j).get("State")
                            .equals(mylist.get(i).get("State")))) {
                tempMap.put("Country", mylist.get(i).get("Country"));
                tempMap.put("State", mylist.get(i).get("State"));
                counstatelist.add(tempMap);
            }
        }
    } else {
        tempMap.put("Country", mylist.get(i).get("Country"));
        tempMap.put("State", mylist.get(i).get("State"));
        counstatelist.add(tempMap);
    }
}
```

Now the **expected output is came**. But I **don't know how this works**. 
I don't know what I am doing wrong,

**Update 2**
I have updated `mylist` with following data.

```
HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("Country", "India");
map1.put("State", "Tamilnadu");
map1.put("Distict", "Ariyalur");

HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("Country", "India");
map2.put("State", "Tamilnadu");
map2.put("Distict", "Salem");

HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
map3.put("Country", "India");
map3.put("State", "Tamilnadu");
map3.put("Distict", "Trichy");

HashMap<String, String> map4 = new HashMap<>();
map4.put("Country", "India");
map4.put("State", "Kerala");
map4.put("Distict", "State1");

HashMap<String, String> map5 = new HashMap<>();
map5.put("Country", "Pak");
map5.put("State", "Kerala");
map5.put("Distict", "State1");

HashMap<String, String> map6 = new HashMap<>();
map6.put("Country", "India");
map6.put("State", "Tamilnadu");
map6.put("Distict", "Trichy");

mylist.add(map1);
mylist.add(map2);
mylist.add(map3);
mylist.add(map4);
mylist.add(map5);
mylist.add(map6);
```

Now the output is

```
[{State=Tamilnadu, Country=India}, {State=Kerala, Country=India}, {State=Kerala, Country=Pak}, {State=Tamilnadu, Country=India}, {State=Tamilnadu, Country=India}]
```

But the output should be

```
[{State=Tamilnadu, Country=India}, {State=Kerala, Country=India}, {State=Kerala, Country=Pak}]
```

Thanks,

Guna

Comment: Consider stating your ordering criteria in a class, and then, solve your problem with Collections.sort(list, myHashMapComparator)

Comment: on what basis you want to short the list?

Comment: Use a debugger to see where the logic breaks.

Comment: Also, you are creating new instances of HashMap just to sort your list. On top of that you lose the district bit of your sorted data.

Comment: On a completely different note, if you need an arraylist of hashmaps, you may be much better off with a proper class that's named after what you need it for, even if it `extends` and ArrayList, containing things that extend `HashMap`s. An arraylist of hashmaps of strings to strings is an almost guaranteed "this needs its own datastructure" signal.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use **MultiMap**, similar type of problem can be handle easily with multiMap.

A **multimap** is like a **Map** but it can map each key to multiple values.

Go through this doc: [Java doc MultiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)

For example:

```
 MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
 mhm.put(key, "A");
 mhm.put(key, "B");
 mhm.put(key, "C");
 Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get(key);
```

**coll** will be a collection containing "A", "B", "C".

PS: I think you can write code as per your requirement but If you wish then I will update my answer exactly for your question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After many search I go with [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> counstatelist = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
    tempMap.put("Country", mylist.get(i).get("Country"));
    tempMap.put("State", mylist.get(i).get("State"));
    counstatelist.add(tempMap);
}
HashSet<HashMap<String, String>> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
hashSet.addAll(counstatelist);
counstatelist.clear();
counstatelist.addAll(hashSet);
System.out.println(counstatelist);
```

Now I got my expected output.

Thanks to all those who tries to help me.

Answer (score 0):

**when i = 4** 
counstatelist = [{State=Tamilnadu, Country=India}, {State=Kerala, Country=India}] 
then the inner loop will executed twice and the check of the if condition would be true for the both executions because it compares the (4th element of mylist) with (1st and 2nd elements only of counstatelist) twice
and insert the 4th element of myList twice too 
So to fix that problem you have to add a break statement after the addition in the inner loop just like that

```
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if ((!counstatelist.get(j).get("Country")
                        .equals(mylist.get(i).get("Country")))
                        || (!counstatelist.get(j).get("State")
                                .equals(mylist.get(i).get("State")))) {
                    tempMap.put("Country", mylist.get(i).get("Country"));
                    tempMap.put("State", mylist.get(i).get("State"));
                    counstatelist.add(tempMap);
                    break;
                }
            }
```